# ForEach not recognizing array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm looping through an array with foreach(), but for some reason, this particular line doesn't seem to like my array. It's strange, because I have another foreach that works with this array in a different file that works correctly. I've tried casting it to an array, but that just leaves me with empty strings returned to my other functions and a nested array.

Array structure:

```
   Array ( 
          [0] => http://example.com/example.html
          [1] => http://developer.com/test.html
   )
```

PHP

```
/*
* Sends forms post submissions to a second source
* 
*/
public function send_to_third_party(){
    //this is how we read options from the options database as seen in options.php
    //get settings
    $formIdsArray = explode(',', get_option('fts_form_id'));
    $formUrlsArray = explode(',', get_option('fts_forward_url'));
    print_r($formUrlsArray);
    add_action("gform_post_submission", "post_again", 10, 2);


    function post_to_url($url, $data) {

           // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
           $options = array(
           'http' => array(
               'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
               'method'  => 'POST',
               'content' => http_build_query($data),
           ),
           );
           $context  = stream_context_create($options);
           $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    }

    function post_again($entry, $form){
          //if this form's ID matches the required id, forward it to corresponding URL
          if(get_option('fts_forward_url')){ //check for empty forwarding URLs
            if(is_array($formUrlsArray))
            {
            foreach($formUrlsArray as $key => $formUrl){
                //post_to_url($formUrl, $entry);
                }
            }
            else
            {
               echo "<pre>"; print_r($formUrlsArray); echo "</pre>";
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in *path* on line *line*
```

EDIT: The foreach is in an inner function inside a public function.

Comment: More info.  Is the foreach in a function?

Comment: try with `is_array($formUrlsArray)` condition and give us the output.

Comment: Can you provide more code? It's very hard to determine that actual issue.

Comment: the error indicates that the variable ``$formUrlsArray`` don't allways contains a array so the ``foreach`` can't loop through.

Comment: its a variable scope issue   `function post_again($entry, $formUrlsArray){`

Comment: Also, dont nest your functions, it will break, if you call send_to_third_party() twice in the same request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, share with us the output.

```
if(is_array($formUrlsArray))
{
    foreach($formUrlsArray as $key => $formUrl){
        post_to_url($formUrl, $entry);
    }
}
else
{
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($formUrlsArray); echo "</pre>";
}
```

also consider typecasting $formUrlsArray:

```
$formUrlsArray = (array) $formsUrlArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue where I was passing an array to a foreach in a function.
Type casting the array before passing it to the foreach solved the issue.

So insert `$formUrlsArray = (array) $formUrlsArray` as per below and it should work.

```
function post_again($entry, $form){
      //if this form's ID matches the required id, forward it to 
      //corresponding URL
      if(get_option('fts_forward_url')){ //check for empty forwarding URLs
      $formUrlsArray = (array) $formUrlsArray
      if(is_array($formUrlsArray))
        {
        foreach($formUrlsArray as $key => $formUrl){
            //post_to_url($formUrl, $entry);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           echo "<pre>"; print_r($formUrlsArray); echo "</pre>";
        }
      }
}
```